# rich:autocomplete multiple in richfaces

Tags: richfaces

I am working with richfaces . I wanted to enable multiple select like we have in the primefaces below:

[image]

I googled it but could not find such in richfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable multiple select by setting @tokens. E.g. `tokens=","`, lets you put in "abc,efgh,ij,klm" which would otherwise be a single value. See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-autocomplete-Interactivity_options).